# fullpage.js go directly to clicked slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, fullpage.js

I'm making an one-page website with fullpage.js.

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/continuous.html

If you look at the above example, when switching between 'First slide' and 'Third slide' using the navigation, the animation will jump from the first to the third slide with also going throught the second slide. Is it possible to jump (but still showing animation) directly to the correct slide without showing the slides inbetween?

Comment: Why don't you try its brother plugin: [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) . It seems to fit you better. No sections will be shown between two non consecutive sections.

Answer (score 0):

**silentMoveTo(section, slide)**

Exactly the same as moveTo but in this case it performs the scroll without animation. A direct jump to the destination.

```
/*Scrolling to the section with the anchor link `firstSlide` and to the 2nd Slide */
$.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('firstSlide', 2);
```

source: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#silentmovetosection-slide

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible to still show the slide animation (from first to third slide) instead of directy showing the third page?